# I got 1 reputation on SO meta, is it a bug?

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

I pinned the SO meta to the SE site switcher.
I looked at my reputation and it is 1.
When I go to SO meta I am not suspended or my reputation is one.
Is this intended?
The SO meta reputation in the site switcher should match the SO reputation.
[image: SO reputation 288, SO meta reputation 1]